# Invalid read of size 1 when accessing a member of a struct

Tags: c, struct, valgrind, memcpy

I've been running into this same issue for a few days now and have managed some workarounds but I need to understand where I am going wrong.

This is the valgrind error which causes a segmentation fault and crash

```
==14609== Invalid read of size 1
==14609==    at 0x4E80F90: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1655)
==14609==    by 0x4E87F56: fprintf (fprintf.c:32)
==14609==    by 0x4017ED: display_tickets (tm_options.c:261)
==14609==    by 0x400E5D: main (tm.c:83)
==14609==  Address 0xa is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

The code I'm trying to run is fairly simple.

```
void display_tickets(tm_type *tm) {

struct stock_data data;
struct stock_node *current;
memcpy(&data, tm->stock->head_stock->data, sizeof(tm->stock->head_stock->data));

  printf("%s", data.ticket_name);  /*THIS WORKS, name is as expected*/
  fprintf(stdout, "Name is %s", 40, data.ticket_name); /*this causes the read error*/

}
```

ticket_name is just a string (size 40), which is a member of "struct stock_data".

Can anyone shed some light it's doing my head in....

Comment: Your format string has one "parameter", you're passing two things. Can't work.

Comment: Any good compiler should have told you that that line is fishy if you'd had compiled with all warning levels switched on. With many compilers on POSIX systems (which seems the case for you) this can be achieved by `-Wall`. Don't ignore any of such warnings, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: just to clarify, I thought this was the same problem I've been having elsewhere in my program. Obviously turn out it isn't. and yes, I should pay careful attention to the compiler from now on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the line:

```
fprintf(stdout, "Name is %s", 40, data.ticket_name);
```

Your specify the format `%s`, which expects the next unused argument to be a string, but you are passing an int (`40`). Remove the `40,` and it should work. (Or did you mean the format to be `%*s`?)

Comment: Wow and here I was getting so frustrated, when you've been at an assignment for this long....things get blurry. Thank you